# How to structure/size isometric sprites

Tags: tilemap, godot, tilesets

I'm taking a look at a isometric asset pack from Kenney, and all the images are 512x256..even images with just a small barrel in it. Seems like a lot of space is wasted?

Is this good practice, to keep everything the same size? What's annoying to me, is that in Godot the image is placed way below the selection, because of all the whitespace in the image:

[image]

So I'm curious how you all make/structure your own tilesets.

Comment: If you were using this in an engine like Unity, it wouldn't matter how much empty space was in the individual tile images since the engine can automatically re-pack them all into an atlas texture for you. So, the simplicity and consistency of exporting each tile the same size doesn't impose a runtime cost. I don't know whether Godot does something similar.

Comment: I see, yeah the space isn't going to matter much..but it does give me the weird position in godot, the 'tile origin' option doesn't seem to do anything either